# replace function with ruby style block

Tags: javascript, ruby, underscore.js

Armed with [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/), I could achieve something fantastic like below:

```
_([1,2,3]).chain().map(function(n) {return n*2}).reduce(function(m,a) {return m +a},0).value()
```

Obviously, the most verbose part is the definition of `function`. Could it be more simpler? Something like:

```
 _([1,2,3]).chain().map( {|n| return n*2} ).reduce({|m,a| return m+2; },0).value()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take delight in writing compact functional programming, check [Functional](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/) (caveat: it takes the non-OOP approach):

```
JS> reduce('+', 0, map('*2', [1, 2, 3]))
12
```

It feels almost like you are writing Haskell ;-)

```
Haskell> foldl (+) 0 (map (*2) [1, 2, 3])
12
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were using [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script) you could write

```
_([1,2,3]).chain().map((n) -> n*2).reduce((m,a) -> m+2, 0).value()
```

using anonymous functions.

JavaScript doesn't have blocks of course.